# How do I split a string chapter, include chapter name using python re?

Tags: python, string

Hi i have a question about re

this is my code

```py
import re
s = '''【chapter list】


【chapter 1】
bob_123

【chapter 2】
check_
....
....
【chapter 3】
AAADDDDCC_AAADDDDCC_AAADDDDCC
AAADDDDCC


【chapter 4】
ADS

'''


s = re.findall(r"【chapter [0-9]+】.*?", s)

#
```

The result of the code above is below.

```py
s = ['【chapter 1】', '【chapter 2】', '【chapter 3】', '【chapter 4】']
```

But I want to split the strings including chapter entries and chapter contents.

```py
ex) s=['【chapter 1】\n bob_123, 【chapter 2】\n check_\n ....\n...., 【chapter 3】AAADDDDCC_AAADDDDCC_AAADDDDCC \nAAADDDDCC...]
```

Please help.

Comment: ctrl + k to format the code in your questions

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works.

```
r"(【chapter [0-9]+】.*?)+((?:\n.+)+)"
```

---

Edit:
Added python compliant code.